# Parse string in Powershell and create a table

Tags: string, powershell, parsing

I have a variable in Powershell that return the following string

```
    S: Title = test S: Title = test2 S: Title = test3 S: Title = test4 
 TE: 2019-01-19T00:00:00Z TE: 2019-01-20T00:00:00Z TE: 2019-01-22T00:00:00Z TE: 2019-01-23T00:00:00Z
```

I'm trying to format this string to have something like (even in a csv file):

```
test        test2        test3       test4
2019-01-19  2019-01-20   2019-01-22  2019-01-23
```

but without success. How can I do this?

Edit: This is the line that generate the string. Basically I want to extract Name and Expiration date of all the entries in a keepass database (I may have found another way using the xml file exported):

```
$entries = & "$kps" -c:ListEntries "$kdbx" -pw:$pass
```

Comment: [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-6])has a `-Delimiter` parameter that might be of use to you `;-)`

Comment: Thanks, but that's the problem: there is no Delimiter such as ; or , or : etc

Comment: Is your 'string' a single (multi-line) string or an array of strings?

Comment: it's a single line

Comment: As there's nothing you can use as a delimiter, you'll need to put in your own. Try using `replace()` to replace strings you don't want with something you can use as a delimiter.

Comment: What do you mean "it's a single line"? Your example clearly shows 2 lines.

Comment: I put in two lines but it's a single line

Comment: Please edit you Question and include the source data EXACTLY as it is. Adding lines just means it's not a true representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit this is a bit excesive use of `.replace()` but there isn't much to work with:

```
$mystring= "    S: Title = test S: Title = test2 S: Title = test3 S: Title = test4 
 TE: 2019-01-19T00:00:00Z TE: 2019-01-20T00:00:00Z TE: 2019-01-22T00:00:00Z TE: 2019-01-23T00:00:00Z "


$MyString.trim().replace(" S: Title = ",",").replace("T00:00:00Z TE: ",",").replace("TE: ","").replace("S: Title = ","").replace("T00:00:00Z","").replace(" ","") | convertfrom-csv
```

Output:

```
test         test2        test3        test4     
----         -----        -----        -----     
2019-01-19   2019-01-20   2019-01-22   2019-01-23
```

It would be easyer (and more overseeable) to implement those steps in the creation of the string.